# Why my ScrollView hide my image in React Native?

Tags: javascript, image, react-native, scrollview

I want to add a `scrollView` in my screen after text and image.

```
return (
    <View>
        <Text>Name</Text>
        <Image source = {{uri : 'myUri' }} style = {styles.image}/>                 
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                <Text>City</Text>
                <Text>Tokyo</Text>
            </View>

            <View>
                <Text>Language</Text>
                <Text>Japanese</Text>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
);
```

Here is the style of my image:

```
image: {
    flex: 1,
    width: null,
    height: null,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginTop: 3,
    marginBottom: 3,
},
```

The image never shows up with the `scrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify a length for your ScrollView?

Because you make the image's width and height null, the image tries to fill the empty spaces of the page. If you don't give your ScrollView a specific height, it wil fill the screen, so your image cannot find an empty space for itself.

You may need to change the height of the image with a specific value, or you can combine your text and image in a different view and give that view a specific height.

```
<View style = {styles.customStyle}> // change your style here
   <Text>Name</Text>
   <Image source = {{uri : 'myUri' }} style = {styles.image}/>
</View>
```

Comment: In this case, is your text (the one before the image) visible?

Comment: Sorry, I edited. My uri wasn't working. Your solution works. Thanks